# Can fielddata_fields be used in mget request?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get the fielddata from a `not_analyzed` field in [Multi Get](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html) query. It is working fine in `_search` queries.

This is what I've tried with no luck:

```
curl -XGET "http://es:9200/articles/article/_mget/?pretty&fielddata_fields=url" -d '{"ids" : ["5763197951"]}'

curl -XGET "http://es:9200/articles/article/_mget/?pretty" -d '{"fielddata_fields": ["url"], "ids" : ["5763197951"]}'

curl -XGET "http://es:9200/articles/article/_mget/?pretty" -d '{"docs" : [{"_id" : "5763197951", "fielddata_fields": ["url"]}]}'
```

It looks like `fielddata_fields` is completely ignored, since I always get this result:

```
{
  "docs" : [ {
    "_index" : "articles",
    "_type" : "article",
    "_id" : "5763197951",
    "_version" : 1,
    "found" : true
  } ]
}
```

I'm running ES version `1.4.4` with JVM: `1.8.0_31`

**Edit**: I just tried the above with a test database running ES `2.2.2` with the same results...